# What is +new Date syntax in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

Sorry if this duplicated.

I saw `+new Date` in a github project then I try it out.

It's return timestamp in type of number.

While `new Date()` return time format in string.

So what is the meaning of `+new Date` syntax and how to implement in my own module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard javascript. Not node specific

When calling a constructor with `new` the parenthesis are optional if it takes no arguments

```
function MyObject () {}

new MyObject();
new MyObject;  // these both create an object
```

The `+` is just a shorthand way of casting to a number.

Its the unary plus operator simmilar to the unary minus operator in `-5`

```
+'123' === 123 // true
```

In the case of `+new Date` this casts a Date object to a number or the current number of milliseconds since the unix epoch. Result is the same as `date.getTime()`.